# how to read a javascript function from json

Tags: node.js

I want to read  values in the function mv from a json object :

```
{ name: 'user_step4#upload',
  data:
   <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff e1 00 4c 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 02 01 12 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 06 ... >,
  size: 6841698,
  encoding: '7bit',
  tempFilePath: '',
  truncated: false,
  mimetype: 'multipart/form-data',
  md5: '226d9791b4e0d637cee207a2f832900e',
  mv: [Function: mv] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is a Buffer data type.
Try to convert to string data type.
`object.data.toString()`

Comment: not the data in data key , i want to read the value in the mv function

Comment: it's some data hidden whit multer

Comment: mv is a function. Can you console.log him to check there data response

Comment: (filePath, callback) => {
      // Determine a propper move function.
      let moveFunc = (options.buffer.length && !options.tempFilePath)
        ? moveFromBuffer(filePath, options)
        : moveFromTemp(filePath, options);
      // Create a folder for a file.
      checkAndMakeDir(fileUploadOptions, filePath);
      // If callback is passed in, use the callback API, otherwise return a promise.
      return isFunc(callback)
        ? moveFunc(callback)
        : new Promise(moveFunc);
    }

Answer (score 0):

`yourJsonObject.data.toString()` will convert your buffer to String.

`yourJsonObject.mv.toString()` will help you to print the function code.

Comment: that  return this
(filePath, callback) => {
      // Determine a propper move function.
      let moveFunc = (options.buffer.length && !options.tempFilePath)
        ? moveFromBuffer(filePath, options)
        : moveFromTemp(filePath, options);
      // Create a folder for a file.
      checkAndMakeDir(fileUploadOptions, filePath);
      // If callback is passed in, use the callback API, otherwise return a promise.
      return isFunc(callback)
        ? moveFunc(callback)
        : new Promise(moveFunc);
    }

Comment: i want to read some params uploading whit my file in fileuploadOptions from ionic 3